# Populating a cell with the values of another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a VBA Script that generates a statement of account report. I have divided the report into sections: 1. The Header, 2. The First Job Entry, 3. Additional Job Entries and 4. The summation bar. Each section has its own hot key short cut. I have only worked on the layout aspect of the sections so far and now I am ready and attempting to write the calculation aspects which is where I am having some issues.

I am new to VBA programming so my question is quite simple. I would like to have the value from one cell populate into another. I was able to get the script to do this already but it was for a string and the string was populated during the writing of the script itself. I would like to have the First Entry be written and **then** have the user go in type a *number* into one cell and then that same number populate into another cell. Essentially I would like for all formulas to be written and ready for the accounts receivable person to simply enter the numbers they need and make their decisions.

Here is the code for the macro the short cut is Shift + ctrl + D. the first thing it does is ask where to place the portion (cell address) and then it asks how many entries (invoices) are needed. The Macro then prints out the entry format required and then loops a copy and paste below this entry for as many entries specified by the user. Here it is:

```
Sub STOACre()
Dim Start As Range
Set Start = Application.InputBox(prompt:="What Cell Address would you like       to start your invoice entries at?", Type:=8)
Dim Entries As Integer
Entries = InputBox(prompt:="How Many Invoices are you entering for this   Project number?")

'This is the Entry portion of the page
 Application.Goto Start
With ActiveCell.Range("A1:G1, f3").Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .bold = True
End With
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Inv.no"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Job.no"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Due Date"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Aging(Days)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Invoice Amount"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Due Amount"
With ActiveCell.Range("A1:G1").Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With ActiveCell.Range("A1:G1").Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
ActiveCell.Range("A1:G1").Font.bold = True
For i = 1 To Entries
    Application.Goto Start
    With ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:G1").Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
   With ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:G1")
        .Copy
        .Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
Next i
ActiveCell.Offset(Entries + 1, 5).Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Sub Total"
 With ActiveCell.Offset(Entries + 1, 0).Range("A1:E1")
    .MergeCells = True
    .FormulaR1C1 = " "
    End With
 End Sub
```

Thank you and sorry to bother with such a simple question. I have seen similar ones posted but they did not seem to work for my situation. Any help and/or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Thanks I'll try this out. Although I have tried something similar with no luck but maybe I missed something without noticing. I was planing on entering this right before the loop under "Due Amount" so that Due amount would reflect "Invoiced Amount" and the formula would be copied to each inserted line. I'll let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Just use formula, if you want cell A1 to equal whatever is put into A2, then do this:

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=A2"
```

Where exactly in the code do you want to define where one cell is supposed to equal another cell? I could help you with more specific code.